# Using a case expression to group by age in SQL

Tags: sql, select, datatable, expression, case

I am currently writing some SQL for a project. I would like to try practicing case expressions, and in this case, practicing grouping records by age.

Here's the table I'm working with: Person

```
Name | Age
-----------
Mike | 32
Angela | 11
Chris | 65
Nat | 20
Sandra | 45
Shane | 82
```

I want to use a case expression to group these these people by age. I'd like to divide people into 
-18 and younger
-19 to 40
-41 and older

So far, I've been trying to write a case expression like this:

```
select name, age
from person
order by
(case
when age < 18 //group first
when (age >= 19 and age < 40 //group second
else //group third
end);
```

Obviously this isn't working. I've been trying to understand case expressions a bit better, can anyone give me some pointers?

Comment: For this particular case, you can just order by age.

Comment: try adding the case expression as a part of select. select name, (case..) as age_group. Then you can group the result of the query in another select query. something like this:
`select count(1) from (select name, age_group...) group by age_group`.

Comment: You should provide the results you want.  Your question mentions "grouping" but your sample query is doing "ordering".

Comment: You've probably moved on from this problem. But I still wanted to point out two things. 1) Age 18 handled right and falls into group three since you used strictly less than in the comparison. 2) You didn't specify how to handle ties. The ordering within groups isn't specified at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you are trying to achieve.

```
select name, age
 from person order by 
 case when age < 18 then 0 when age >=19 and age <=40 then 1 else 2 end
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try using a `CASE` expression to form the age groups:

```
SELECT
    Name,
    Age,
    CASE WHEN Age <= 18 THEN 'young'
         WHEN Age <= 40 THEN 'middle'
         ELSE 'older' END AS age_group
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    Age;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
   Select  AgeGroup, count(distinct *) as 
    count_names
   from(SELECT NAME, CASE WHEN 
      Age <= 
      18 THEN 'young (1-18)'
     WHEN Age <= 40 THEN 'Middle(19- 
     40)'
     ELSE 'older (40-above)' END as 
      AgeGroup) group by AgeGroup
```